# How do I secure a non-interactive authentication system for an unlimited number of clients?

Tags: authentication, encryption, hash

I am struggling on thinking how to do an auth system which allows arbitrary clients that share the same source code but have random uuid based identifiers to authenticate. A requisite for that is that the clients must not need human interaction to login to that server, think of it kind of an automatic IoT device that needs to login to a central server but can't receive user input.

For my use case, I don't need it to be a very secure system. But at least it would be nice to have some kind of impediment to attackers.

My first approach is using the identifier uuid as a username, and a function that hashes the identifier with other dynamic values along with a secret, but that seems to me a bit hacky... The hash generated must be constant for each device.

The clients can't use non-simple hashing/encryption methods. Here's a list of things they can compute: MD5 hash, SHA1 hash, XORs between two base64 strings, SHA256 hash and ARCFOUR.

The server, however, can compute any encryption/hashing algorithm, and the identifier of the device is public and can be accessed by anyone. However, the source code is private and the communication is made with https.

Any ideas of how to achieve this with a better auth method? (Taking into account these restrictions)

Answer (score 1):

You say the IoT device cannot receive user input. Can it display or communicate anything to the user? If so, you could consider the [OAuth2 device flow](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/device-flow/).

Your IoT device would be polling the authorization server. 
You can use the browser on your phone or computer to authorize the IoT device.